# Import JSON Lines into Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jsonlines

I want to import a JSON lines file into pandas. I tried to import it like a regular JSON file, but it did not work:

```
js = pd.read_json (r'C:\Users\Name\Downloads\profilenotes.jsonl')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This medium article](https://sundararamanp.medium.com/a-relatively-faster-approach-for-reading-json-lines-file-into-pandas-dataframe-90b57353fd38) provides a fairly simple answer, which can be adapted to be even shorter. All you need to do is read each line then parse each line with `json.loads()`. Like this:

```
import json
import pandas as pd


lines = []
with open(r'test.jsonl') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

line_dicts = [json.loads(line) for line in lines]
df_final = pd.DataFrame(line_dicts)

print(df_final)
```

As [cgobat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4450498/cgobat) pointed out in a comment, the medium article adds a few extra unnecessary steps, which have been optimized in this answer.

Comment: There's no need for an intermediate DataFrame, because you can directly initialize a DataFrame using an iterable of dicts. Just create a list like `line_dicts = [json.loads(line) for line in lines]`, then you can go straight to your final DataFrame by simply calling `df_final = pd.DataFrame(line_dicts)`.

Comment: Also, line 12 here (`df_inter['json_element'].apply(json.loads)`) doesn't do anything. Since you're not calling it `inplace` and you don't assign it to anything, nothing happens to the result of that statement. Plus, you're already doing the same operation in the following line.

Comment: I don't know if there is any difference with the above answer in terms of performance, but it also works as a two-liner: ```with open('test.jsonl', 'r') as file: df = pd.DataFrame([json.loads(line) for line in file.read().splitlines()])``` . By doing so, you get the final dataframe without keeping the intermediate variables in memory.

Answer (score 0):

If your lines have nested expressions like `{"A": {"B":3235,"C":2142}}` and you want the dataframe to have columns like `A.B, A.C` instead of `A:{"B":3235, "C":2142}`, you should use:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

lines = []
with open(r'test.jsonl') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
data = [json.loads(line) for line in x.strip().split('\n')]
df = pd.normalize_json(data)
```

Comment: What is the difference to the former answer here?

Comment: The answer they give gave only the major columns like ```A```, with their values being nested expressions ```'{"B":45,"C":3235}'```. With normalized, those become columns ```A.B, A.C``` which is much better for me since each value has its own column.